# How to add Android SDK for Android L in IntelliJ

Tags: android, intellij-idea, android-5.0-lollipop

When I go to Project Structure -> SDK, then [+] button (Add) Android SDK, I can't see Android L on the dropdown list.

Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 1):

It hasn't appeared for me as well, I just updated SDK Tools, SDK Platform-tools and Build-tools, then entered the SDK Manager once again - and it was there.

Answer (score 1):

Go to your "Project Stucture" (Right click on your project folder or press F4 when your project folder is selected).

Then go to the "SDKs" menu, click on the "Add" button (to create a new SDK for IntelliJ), go to your "android-sdks" folder, validate it, then just select the new sdk released.

Tadaa, you just add the new sdk.

Unfortunately IntelliJ doesn't handle the new preview engine. I'm afraid even with the new version (v13.1.3), you'll still not be able to use the preview. I think just Android Studio can handle it.

Hope it will help you :)

Answer (score 0):

Update SDK Tools, restart sdk manager and it should appear